# How to call another Storyboard as a popover?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, storyboard

Assumed there is a '**ViewControllerOne**' in Storyboard '**A**'. If a user tapped a button on it, '**ViewControllerOne**' will call Storyboard '**B**' and show it as a popover on the screen. It seems that I can't find any references for my problem.

I would like to call another Storyboard from a Storyboard and show it as a popover, is it possible to do this? Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

I've tried the solution provided by @Sohil R. Memon, but I got an error :

```
reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fe69a841f00>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PaymentOnly''
```

I've added the RestorationID to the View Controller.

But if I change the code to :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PaymentOnly", bundle:nil)
let navigationController: UINavigationController = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
let viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! PaymentOnlyViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

It worked but doesn't pop over the view. Below is the code from @Sohil R. Memon :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PaymentOption" {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "PaymentOnly", bundle: nil)
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PaymentOnly") as! PaymentOnlyViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously present / popover any of the `UIViewController` from anywhere in any `UIStoryBoard`.

Expecting this is your first `UIViewController` and you want to call any other `UIViewController` from other `UIStoryBoard`. So for that find the below code:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard_name", bundle: nil)
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("chatVC") as! ChatVC
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This way you can present or push any of the `UIViewController`.

[Popover reference link](http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html).

Comment: `ChatVC` is our class of particular `UIViewController`. You can go with your class to instantiate any of the `UIViewController`

Comment: Thank you, please see the edit above, I've tried as you suggested but I got an error..

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 have you given the `identifier` to storyboard?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 can you post the screenshot of both the storyboard?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 it means the controller is presented, right? But don't work as you have expected?

Comment: Yes, the controller is presented. Do I miss something there? I've tried using the same name as the StoryboardID.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 Bro, now you need to implement that how to popover the `UIViewController`. Here is the link to do so: http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html